# React - Trying to pass a function to child component but gives an object

Tags: reactjs, function

I'm trying to pass an async function (getChannels) to a child component in React. But when I try to use it in the child component it gives an error saying that it's not a function. When I console.log it from the child it's indeed an object.

I'm calling getChannels at the end of updateChannel.

The result when I console.log(getChannel) from the child

[image]

Here is the parent:

```
const Home = () => {

  let {authToken, logout, user} = useContext(AuthContext)
  let [currentChannel, setCurrentChannel] = useState({})
  let [channelName, setChannelName] = useState([])
  let [channels, setChannels] = useState([])

  let getChannels = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/channel/`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
        },
    })
    let data = await response.json()
    if(response.status === 200){
      setChannels(data)
    }else{
      logout()
    }
  }

  useEffect(
    ()=>{getChannels()},[]
  )

  return (
      <div className='channel-control'>
              <form className='new-channel' onSubmit={e => {createChannel(e)}}>
                  <input
                  className='channel-log-input'
                  name='newchannel'
                  placeholder='Channel Name'
                  type="text"
                  onChange={e=>setChannelName(e.target.value)}></input>
                  <input className="submit-button-channel" type="submit" value="  Submit  "/>
              </form>
          <UpdateChannel currentChannel={currentChannel} getChannels={getChannels}/>
        </div>

    </div>
    <ChatBox currentChannel={currentChannel}/>
  </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

and the Child:

```
export default function UpdateChannel(currentChannel, getChannels) {

    let {authToken, user, logout} = useContext(AuthContext)
    let [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    let [newUser, setNewUser] = useState([])
    let [channelUsers, setChannelUsers] = useState([])

    let updateChannel = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let usersList = currentChannel.currentChannel.users.map(x => x.id)
        usersList.push(parseInt(newUser))

        const data = {"users" : [... new Set(usersList)],}

        const response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/channel/${currentChannel.currentChannel.id}/`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + String(authToken.access)
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        if(response.status==200){
            alert('New user added!')
        }
        getChannels()
      }

    return (
        <form className='add-user' onSubmit={e => updateChannel(e)}>
            <select onChange={e => {setNewUser(e.target.value)}}>
                <option selected="selected"> Add a New User</option>
                {
                    users.map((user,index) => (
                        <option key={index} value={user.id}>{user.username}</option>
                    ))
                }
            </select>
            <input className="submit-button-channel" type="submit" value="  Submit  "/>
        </form>
    )
```

For readibilty I have cut a function in the parent component that set the currentChannel that is also passed to the child.

Comment: Change `UpdateChannel(currentChannel, getChannels)` to `UpdateChannel({currentChannel, getChannels})`

Answer (score -2):

The answer from Konrad solves it:

> Change UpdateChannel(currentChannel, getChannels) to
> UpdateChannel({currentChannel, getChannels})